# Only allow a single dot point in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an input field which has:

```
$(".double").alphanumeric({allow:" ",ichars:"`~!@#$%^&*=_+[]\\{}|;\":,/<>?'-()\/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDFEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"});
```

validation applied to it.

I need to further restrict entry so that only a single decimal place can be added e.g. 100.00 or 255.95

The input is used for currency so I need to only allow 1 decimal point. At the moment its allow 100.00.00 which messes up the system!

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?  You've posted jQuery, with some plugin.  Are you trying to validate the data server-side?

Comment: Sorry! I am just use to posting PHP questions.

Comment: "which messes up the system" I hope you're not relying on client-side validation to prevent server-side screw-ups, because that is bound to fail!

Comment: Not at all but for some reason it stores the 95.00 out of the 250.95.00. It doesnt mess up the system literally, just doesnt store the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that will only allow positive/negative decimal numbers

```
^[-]?((\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|(\.\d+))$
```

With jquery you can test the value

```
if (/^[-]?((\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|(\.\d+))$/.test($(".double").val())) { .... }
```

Comment: A bit shortened: `^-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$`

Comment: This works great however another question, how would I go about only allowing 1 occurrence of a decimal point? It still allows me to type 100.00.00 but validates invalid upon submit.

Comment: That is much more challenging and would qualify as a separate question. You can search Google and Stackoverflow, and there are a number of interesting answers to be found.

Answer (score 1):

A simple function to allow an optional leading + or - and only digits with an optional decimal place is:

```
function validate(value) {
  var re = /^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
  return re.test(value);
}
```

However since you want money, you might want:

```
  var re = /^[-+]?\d+(\.\d\d)?$/;
```

which will require two digits after the decimal place, if there is one.